Error Code 1411 on MYSQL that persists past any solution I can find
Apologies, I have seen a few of these questions regarding Error 1411 and I have gone through and read solutions but none seem to work for me here.
Using MYSQL, I have a table where the column transaction_date is a text type. The dates are listed as 1/1/2023. However, when I attempt to run the following query:
UPDATE coffee_shop_sales
SET transaction_date = str_to_date(transaction_date, "%d-%m-%Y");

It gives me the message:

Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '1/1/2023' for function str_to_date.

Even when I switch the d and the m in that update statement, it changes nothing, same message. How can I update this column from a text type to a date column? Where am I going wrong?
I have attached the video of where I am getting this data from, the timestamp specifically is 47:40 when he runs this. I noticed he also had the error code 1411 but for whatever reason his data does work? Not sure.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgz0msTZtX8&t=4828s
Thank you in advance!!

You are trying to put a date into a datetime field, you have only formatted the date.  per
Mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/datetime.html#:~:text=The%20DATE%20type%20is%20used,both%20date%20and%20time%20parts.

MYSQL Date format  is in this format YYYY-MM-DD .

Peculiar that if transaction_date is a TEXT datatype, you'd cast to a date and update to the same value. In any case though, since you have forward slashes '%d/%m/%Y' would be a better bet than hyphens '%d-%m-%Y' . But you'll still be left with the problem of having transaction_date be a poor datatype.

Thank you all! I actually just figured it out. If I run the query as the way the column data is setup AKA month, day, year in this instance, then I can use the query:
UPDATE coffee_shop_sales
SET transaction_date = str_to_date(transaction_date, "%m/%d/%Y");
Notice I used slashes similar to what the data showed already in m/d/yyy format.
From here I can update/alter my table using
ALTER TABLE coffee_shop_sales
MODIFY COLUMN transaction_date DATE
This then allows me to make the change from a text column to a date column. I appreciate all of your input you guys!!

@Danimal It's not a datetime field, it's a text field.

It seems like you got confused between STR_TO_DATE() and DATE_FORMAT(). The format string for STR_TO_DATE() is the format of the input, not the desired output (which is a datetime, not a string).

I faced the same problem and solved it by using the "%m/%d/%Y" format instead of the "%d-%m-%Y":
UPDATE coffee_shop_sales
SET transaction_date = STR_TO_DATE(transaction_date, "%m/%d/%Y");
Hopefully, this will help.
